# Combine similar regexp check to one JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not familiar with RegExp JS, and I need some help

```
if (/[\-]{2}/.test(value) || /[\_]{2}/.test(value) || /[\.]{2}/.test(value) || /[\@]{2}/.test(value)) {}
```

How do I combine this code to make it more efficient?

This one does exactly what I needed, but I think it can be combined

To be clear, I need to check a string for any of .-_@ these consecutive characters, for example:

```
// "." == false
// ".." == true
// "..." == true
// ".-" == false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simple version:

```
if (/([-_.@])\1/.test(value)) {}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W29EKm/1/tests).

Explanation:

- `(` start a matching group

  - `[-_.@]` any character in the character set consisting of of `-`, `_`, `.`, and `@`
- `)` end the matching group
- `\1` match whatever was in the first (in this case, only) matching group, again.

Note that you don't need to escape

- `_` or `@` ever,
- `.` in a character set (`[...]`), or
- `-` if it's the first or last character in a character set.

Also note that this situation is so straightforward that there's not much point to anything fancy. `/--|__|\.\.|@@/` works just as well.

Comment: Thank You, especially for the clarification

Answer (score -2):

```js
let rx = /(\.|-|_|@)\1+/;

console.log(rx.test('..')); // true
console.log(rx.test('...')); // true
console.log(rx.test('.-.')); // false
console.log(rx.test('--')); // true
```

The `\1` will match the previous captured group.

https://regex101.com/r/keKqc8/1